# how to close visibility of "create new folder" in jfilechooser

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I have aimed to close "create new folder" button on the [file chooser](http://www.stats.govt.nz/infoshare/(X(1)S(t032ok55bbscpp2oayrwka45))/help/images/figures/figure7.1.2.gif). Is it possible to set visibility of "create new folder" button on the file chooser ? I can set visibility of first component which row start with "look in" words to off but I want set visibility of only "create new folder" not all of them. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2):

Two suggestions:

You can make the button disabled by accessing the default Action and disabling the Action:

```
Action folder = fileChooser.getActionMap().get("New Folder");
folder.setEnabled( false );
```

Or you can use reflection to access the button and make the button invisible:

```
//JButton button = SwingUtils.getDescendantOfType(
//  JButton.class, fileChooser, "ToolTipText", "Create New Folder");
//button.setVisible(false);
```

For this approach you will need to use the [Swing Utils](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/13/swing-utils/) class.

Here is a quick demo showing both approaches:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();

        Action folder = fileChooser.getActionMap().get("New Folder");
        folder.setEnabled( false );

        // Make the button invisible

        //JButton button = SwingUtils.getDescendantOfType(
        //  JButton.class, fileChooser, "ToolTipText", "Create New Folder");
        //button.setVisible(false);

        fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used icon name to close buttons. My implementation is ;

```
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();

// operations related with adjusting JFileChooser user interface

closeButton(fileChooser, "FileChooser.newFolderIcon");
closeButton(fileChooser, "FileChooser.upFolderIcon");
```

Main function which is going to be called to dis-appear buttons on user interface

```
void closeButton(JFileChooser fileChooser, String label){
    Icon icon = UIManager.getIcon(label);
    closeButtonHelper(fileChooser.getComponents(), icon);
}

void closeButtonHelper(Component[] containers, Icon icon) {
    for(Object iterator:containers){

        if(iterator instanceof JButton){

            Icon temp = icon.getIcon();

            if(temp != null && temp == icon){
                 (JButton.class.cast(iterator)).setVisible(false);
            }

        } else 
        if(iterator instanceof Container){
            doVisibleHelper(Container.class.cast(iterator).getComponents(), icon);
        }
    }
}
```

For toggle button, just add new if-then-else statement, like;

```
if(iterator instanceof JToggleButton){

    Icon temp = icon.getIcon();

    if(temp != null && temp == icon){
         (JToggleButton.class.cast(iterator)).setVisible(false);
    }

} else
```